# Not sure how to query Oracle Apex 19.1 tables from TOAD

Tags: oracle, oracle-apex

I've installed Oracle Apex 19.1 on Oracle XE 18c. I then created an Apex workspace for which Apex automatically creates a schema which I called `MYSCHEMA`. Apex reports "Database user `MYSCHEMA` created with default tablespace `APEX_1270566619000339` using datafile `D:\APP\USER\PRODUCT\18.0.0\ORADATA\XE\XEPDB1\APEX_1270566619000339.DBF"`. I also created a table in `MYSCHEMA` called `EMPLOYEES`.

I previously had a 11g XE which I uninstalled and replaced with the Oracle XE 18c. I could connect using the same XE database from that previous database in TOAD. It automatically picks up the new `OraDB18Home1`. I didn't change the `tnsnames.ora`. I can connect to the `MYSCHEMA` user using the same password as `SYS`.

However I don't see the `EMPLOYEES` table created in Apex when I use

```
select *
from   all_tables
where  table_name like '%EMPLOYEE%';
```

Where am I going wrong?

PS. I have now noticed that "Connect as `SYSDBA`" was on and it fails to connect to the user `MYSCHEMA` if I choose "Connect as Normal". I have tried all the passwords (2) I have used in setting this up. Not sure if there is a default password I should be using.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I then created an Apex workspace for which Apex automatically creates a schema which I called MYSCHEMA

You can do that, but don't have to. If you already have a schema in your database which contains tables that will be used while developing an Apex application, you can assign that schema to the workspace.

But OK - you chose to create a new schema.

As you can connect as `SYS` (which has to be `AS SYSDBA`), do so. Change `MYSCHEMA`'s password by running

```
alter user myschema identified by some_password;
```

Then create a new connection in TOAD, using `MYSCHEMA` as username and `SOME_PASSWORD` as its password. That connection will be `NORMAL`.

Comment: Would this not prevent Apex from accessing the `MYSCHEMA` schema, because I changed the password?

Comment: It shouldn't. If you connect to Apex Admin and go to "Manage Workspace to Schema Assignments", you aren't required to enter any password.

Comment: APEX can proxy connect to any schema, it doesn't need to know the actual password for your account.

Comment: I get this error `ORA-01918: user 'MYSCHEMA' does not exist`. Can I create a new user to access this schema and what commands would I use to do so?

Comment: It looks like my issues are related to the new PDB features of the 18c database. I'm not sure how to use TOAD to connect to the Oracle XE 18c database even after creating a new user for that tablespace.

Comment: Finally figured it out. Had to connect using TOAD Direct mode and specifying the Service Name as the PDB (XEPDB1).

Comment: Excellent! I'm glad you fixed it. Thank you for letting us know.